# Strange exercise Jordan normal form

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

I have the following excercise that I cannot answer:

Imagine that you have measured two entries $\tilde{A}_{11},\tilde{A}_{22}$ of the matrix $\tilde{A}=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}\\1+\epsilon & 1 \\ 0 &1-\epsilon \end{smallmatrix}\right)$. I guess this means, that the 1 and the 0 are the same as in the actual matrix $A$. (epsilon is not further specified in this excercise) Now the question is: How small does the maximum error of measurement $\delta=\text{max}_{i=1,2} |A_{ii}-\tilde{A}_{ii}|$ have to be, so that we can be sure to get two Jordan normalform of A?

I have no idea, what this means. What further confuses me, is that if the entries on the diagonal of A wouldn't be the same, we would have two different eigenvalues, so A would be diagonalizable and we would get two Jordan blocks. But even if we only have one and the same number on the diagonal of A, the geometric multiplicity would be as far as I see $1$, so we would always get only one Jordan block. But I don't see how this (possibly wrong thinking) is associated to the error of some measurement here?

I am thankful for every idea how this excercise might be meant!

Comment: Your thinking sounds right, and sounds like what they want. In $\tilde A$ the diagonal entries are $2\epsilon$ apart, so we could move them towards each other, each by $\epsilon$, to get a matrix with one Jordan block. On the other hand, if $\delta < \epsilon$, then $A$ still has two distinct diagonal entries, so it has two Jordan blocks.

Comment: This exercise is fundamentally tied to mechanical computation.   Fixed-precision algorithms will have a single Jordan block for $\epsilon$ sufficiently small.  Typically if $1+\epsilon=1$ in your computer architecture then there will be a single block.